# Replace everything between two strings with numbers i++ {0},{1}

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

Have mechanism that replaces strings like .NET `string.Format` in javascript `("{0} - {1}",'a','b')` would result `"a - b"`.

I am looking for mechanism that would Replace everything between two strings with {0}{1}...

Example :

```
var str = "([OrderDate] >= Func:{TheApplication().GetProfileAttr('TestDate')} ) and [OrderDate] < 1/1/2013 AND [Name] = Func:{TheApplication().GetProfileAttr('Name')}"
stringFormatProducer(str,"Func:{","}");
```

would give result

```
"([OrderDate] >= {0} ) and [OrderDate] < 1/1/2013 AND [Name] = {1}"
```

I have this mechanism done in horrid way where I am splitting it on `Func:{` then `}` then iterating over it, I am sure someone already has a better solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan wtf? It has as much in common as word formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened there? I didn't know why the thread closed as I don't have mod powers... as far as I'm aware anyway. I reopened.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you have a gold badge in the tag you can close it as a duplicate like a mod

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well good job! I am looking for opposite mechanism

Comment: @laaposto ah that explains it, thanks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-superpowers?cb=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = 0;

str.replace(/Func:{[^}]+}/g, function(c) {
    return '{' + i++ + '}';
});
```

Or more flexible way:

```
var i = 0,
    func = 'Func:';

str.replace(new RegExp(func + '{[^}]+}', 'g'), function(c) {
    return '{' + i++ + '}';
});
```

A complete method for you:

```
String.prototype.createFormattingString = function(prefix, open, close) {
    var re = new RegExp(prefix + open + '[^' + close + ']+' + close, 'g'),
        i = 0;

    return this.replace(re, function(c) {
        return '{' + i++ + '}';
    });
};

'(VAR > Func:{ some text })'.createFormattingString('Func:', '{', '}');
'(VAR > Func:[ some text ])'.createFormattingString('Func:', '\\[', '\\]');
```

Comment: @LIUFA This is not really correct. I have posted the better solution.

Comment: Technically I owe you one more +1 cause you also fixed a bug :)